# Turn off automatic capitalization on windows phone auto complete

Tags: 8.0, keyboard, autocorrect

When I type on Windows Phone 8 I want to be able to pick and choose what I capitalize.

If I type 'san francisco' I get 'san Francisco'. To get all lowercase I'd need to  tap 'Francisco' and choose 'francisco' from the auto complete.

What I really want to do is have it left lowercase, and hit 'francisco' and see 'Francisco' in the auto complete. At present the default ends up being inconsistent, or requires two extra taps if I want it to be 'as i typed it'.

The same applies to I or Israel. I don't suppose many people are typing python code on their Windows Phone devices, but it would help for that too.

Is there any that we can override this, either now or that we might be able to in the future. Even via another 'language' (variation of English) or keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible in this release, sorry.

If you want to send feedback to Microsoft about this, I've listed a number of feedback routes for wp on this page - http://dfwiki.devfish.net/technology.Microsoft-feedback-routes.ashx .